# Linked List - append e push

Tags: c++, lista, struct, lista-encadeada

Estou tentando aprender Linked List e fiz o seguinte código:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef struct snode {
    int data;
    snode *next;
} node;

void start(node ** head) {

    (*head)->next = NULL;
}

void push(node **head, int val) {
    node *no = new node();
    no->data = val;
    no->next = *head;
    *head = no;
}
void append(node **head, int val) {
    node *newnode = new node();
    node *last = *head;

    newnode->data = val;
    newnode->next = NULL;

    if ((*head)->next == NULL ) {
        (*head) = newnode;
        return;
    }
    while (last->next != NULL) {
        last = last->next;
    }
    last->next = newnode;
    return;
}
void print(node *head) {
    node *temp = new node();
    temp = head;
    if (temp->next == NULL) {
        cout << "Node Vazio\n"; return;
    }
    while (temp != NULL) {
        cout << "Valor: " << temp->data << endl;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
int main() {
    node * lista = new node();
    //start(&lista);
    //append(&lista, 2);
    push(&lista, 8);
    append(&lista, 5);
    push(&lista, 10);
    append(&lista, 200);
    append(&lista, 2213);
    print(lista);

    getchar();

    return 1;
}
```

O problema é o que ele está retornando:

```
Valor: 10
Valor: 8
Valor: 0
Valor: 5
Valor: 200
Valor: 2213
```

O `Valor: 0` não era para estar aparecendo...
Alguém da um help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O problema é que a lista está a ser iniciada com um nó, que não foi inicializado em relação ao `data` ou `next`:

```
node * lista = new node();
```

Que por acaso ficou com o `data` a 0 e o `next` a 0 (`NULL`) também, caso contrário nem funcionaria. A inicialização correta será então:

```
node * lista = NULL;
```

Para além disso a função append tem um bloco incorreto:

```
if ((*head)->next == NULL ) {
    (*head) = newnode;
    return;
}
```

Que diz que se a lista só tem 1 elemento então passa a ser o novo nó. Isso faz perder o nó que já tinha! E removendo este `if` fica funcional. Podemos ainda testar se a lista está vazia nesta função que eu penso que era o objetivo do `if` anterior, fazendo:

```
void append(node **head, int val) {
    if (head == NULL) {
        push(head, val); //se está vazia usa a função de adição à cabeça, que lida bem com NULL
        return;
    }

    node *newnode = new node();
    node *last = *head;

    newnode->data = val;
    newnode->next = NULL;

    while (last->next != NULL) {
        last = last->next;
    }

    last->next = newnode;
}
```

É importante de reparar que o teste de lista vazia no `append` está feito antes de se criar o nó, que antes não estava e por isso tinha uma fuga de memória.

O `print` também tem uma fuga de memória:

```
void print(node *head) {
    node *temp = new node();
    temp = head;
    ...
```

Aqui criou-se um nó e guardou-se o seu endereço de memória no ponteiro `temp`, que logo de seguida foi alterado para apontar para o nó `head`. Logo o nó inicialmente criado ficou perdido em memória. O que se pretende é criar só o ponteiro e por a apontar diretamente para `head`, para posteriormente se poder navegar:

```
void print(node *head) {
    node *temp = head;
    ...
```